# как поменять текст TextView?

Tags: textview

у меня есть два layout.xml один main.xml другой item.xml. Как я могу поменять текст item.xml в коде MainActivity.java? Через findViewById(R.id.text) и text.setText() не получается.

Comment: Расставляйте правильные теги с важной информацией, что бы люди понимали, о чем Вы вообще ведете речь и с чем работаете(язык, устройства, фреймворки, etc). Почти в каждом языке и UI для них есть элемент TextView.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поменять через `Strings.xml`, и из `MainActivity` вызвать `R.strings.textValue`